# What is issue with STM32 Virtual Com Port? I can not open it

Tags: stm32, usbserial, nucleo, cubemx, truestudio

I have Nucleo STM32H743ZI board. I'm using CubeMX HAL (I tried several versions) and TrueStudio. "Virtual COM port" appearances in Windows 10 (I tried default Windows driver and ST driver) but I can not open port. My C# program write me "The parameter is incorrect" when I try open it:

```
SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM8", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
port.Open(); // System.IO.IOException: 'The parameter is incorrect.'
```

same message writes me program Realterm, PuTTY do nothing and "Tera Term" program works correct - I can send and receive data to my MCU program.

May anyone know what is it?

In my C# program and in terminal programs I use same parameters

USB Device viewer information:

```
            [Port1]  :  STMicroelectronics Virtual COM Port


            Is Port User Connectable:         yes
            Is Port Debug Capable:            no
            Companion Port Number:            17
            Companion Hub Symbolic Link Name: USB#ROOT_HUB30#4&2f29167c&0&0#{f18a0e88-c30c-11d0-8815-00a0c906bed8}
            Protocols Supported:
             USB 1.1:                         yes
             USB 2.0:                         yes
             USB 3.0:                         no

            Device Power State:               PowerDeviceD0

                   ---===>Device Information<===---
            English product name: "STM32 Virtual ComPort"

            ConnectionStatus:                  
            Current Config Value:              0x01  -> Device Bus Speed: Full (is not SuperSpeed or higher capable)
            Device Address:                    0x0A
            Open Pipes:                           3

                      ===>Device Descriptor<===
            bLength:                           0x12
            bDescriptorType:                   0x01
            bcdUSB:                          0x0200
            bDeviceClass:                      0x02  -> This is a Communication Device
            bDeviceSubClass:                   0x00
            bDeviceProtocol:                   0x00
            bMaxPacketSize0:                   0x40 = (64) Bytes
            idVendor:                        0x0483 = STMicroelectronics
            idProduct:                       0x5740
            bcdDevice:                       0x0200
            iManufacturer:                     0x01
                 English (United States)  "STMicroelectronics"
            iProduct:                          0x02
                 English (United States)  "STM32 Virtual ComPort"
            iSerialNumber:                     0x03
                 English (United States)  "354BB9433137"
            bNumConfigurations:                0x01

                      ---===>Open Pipes<===---

                      ===>Endpoint Descriptor<===
            bLength:                           0x07
            bDescriptorType:                   0x05
            bEndpointAddress:                  0x82  -> Direction: IN - EndpointID: 2
            bmAttributes:                      0x03  -> Interrupt Transfer Type
            wMaxPacketSize:                  0x0008 = 0x08 bytes
            bInterval:                         0x10

                      ===>Endpoint Descriptor<===
            bLength:                           0x07
            bDescriptorType:                   0x05
            bEndpointAddress:                  0x01  -> Direction: OUT - EndpointID: 1
            bmAttributes:                      0x02  -> Bulk Transfer Type
            wMaxPacketSize:                  0x0040 = 0x40 bytes
            bInterval:                         0x00

                      ===>Endpoint Descriptor<===
            bLength:                           0x07
            bDescriptorType:                   0x05
            bEndpointAddress:                  0x81  -> Direction: IN - EndpointID: 1
            bmAttributes:                      0x02  -> Bulk Transfer Type
            wMaxPacketSize:                  0x0040 = 0x40 bytes
            bInterval:                         0x00

                   ---===>Full Configuration Descriptor<===---

                      ===>Configuration Descriptor<===
            bLength:                           0x09
            bDescriptorType:                   0x02
            wTotalLength:                    0x0043  -> Validated
            bNumInterfaces:                    0x02
            bConfigurationValue:               0x01
            iConfiguration:                    0x00
            bmAttributes:                      0xC0  -> Self Powered
            MaxPower:                          0x32 = 100 mA

                      ===>Interface Descriptor<===
            bLength:                           0x09
            bDescriptorType:                   0x04
            bInterfaceNumber:                  0x00
            bAlternateSetting:                 0x00
            bNumEndpoints:                     0x01
            bInterfaceClass:                   0x02  -> This is Communications (CDC Control) USB Device Interface Class
            bInterfaceSubClass:                0x02
            bInterfaceProtocol:                0x01
            iInterface:                        0x00
              -> This is a Communications (CDC Control) USB Device Interface Class

                      ===>Descriptor Hex Dump<===
            bLength:                           0x05
            bDescriptorType:                   0x24
            05 24 00 10 01 
              -> This is a Communications (CDC Control) USB Device Interface Class

                      ===>Descriptor Hex Dump<===
            bLength:                           0x05
            bDescriptorType:                   0x24
            05 24 01 00 01 
              -> This is a Communications (CDC Control) USB Device Interface Class

                      ===>Descriptor Hex Dump<===
            bLength:                           0x04
            bDescriptorType:                   0x24
            04 24 02 02 
              -> This is a Communications (CDC Control) USB Device Interface Class

                      ===>Descriptor Hex Dump<===
            bLength:                           0x05
            bDescriptorType:                   0x24
            05 24 06 00 01 

                      ===>Endpoint Descriptor<===
            bLength:                           0x07
            bDescriptorType:                   0x05
            bEndpointAddress:                  0x82  -> Direction: IN - EndpointID: 2
            bmAttributes:                      0x03  -> Interrupt Transfer Type
            wMaxPacketSize:                  0x0008 = 0x08 bytes
            bInterval:                         0x10

                      ===>Interface Descriptor<===
            bLength:                           0x09
            bDescriptorType:                   0x04
            bInterfaceNumber:                  0x01
            bAlternateSetting:                 0x00
            bNumEndpoints:                     0x02
            bInterfaceClass:                   0x0A  -> This is a CDC Data USB Device Interface Class
            bInterfaceSubClass:                0x00
            bInterfaceProtocol:                0x00
            iInterface:                        0x00

                      ===>Endpoint Descriptor<===
            bLength:                           0x07
            bDescriptorType:                   0x05
            bEndpointAddress:                  0x01  -> Direction: OUT - EndpointID: 1
            bmAttributes:                      0x02  -> Bulk Transfer Type
            wMaxPacketSize:                  0x0040 = 0x40 bytes
            bInterval:                         0x00

                      ===>Endpoint Descriptor<===
            bLength:                           0x07
            bDescriptorType:                   0x05
            bEndpointAddress:                  0x81  -> Direction: IN - EndpointID: 1
            bmAttributes:                      0x02  -> Bulk Transfer Type
            wMaxPacketSize:                  0x0040 = 0x40 bytes
            bInterval:                         0x00
```

Comment: I am tried C++ Qt program: on Windows 10 don't work, on Ubuntu works (but slow ~256 kbit/s Request - Acknowledge protocol)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem, i could read the device and see which com port but i could not open one. (for a CDC)

then i encountered following post with the last answer having the solution for my problem:
https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkgIYSAZ/unable-to-configure-serial-port-error-for-usb-cdc

there it mentions you need to add several lines if you want to communicate RS232 through a VCP.

I added following in usbd_cdc_if.c file:

```
/*******************************************************************************/
/* Line Coding Structure                                                       */
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Offset | Field       | Size | Value  | Description                          */
/* 0      | dwDTERate   |   4  | Number |Data terminal rate, in bits per second*/
/* 4      | bCharFormat |   1  | Number | Stop bits                            */
/*                                        0 - 1 Stop bit                       */
/*                                        1 - 1.5 Stop bits                    */
/*                                        2 - 2 Stop bits                      */
/* 5      | bParityType |  1   | Number | Parity                               */
/*                                        0 - None                             */
/*                                        1 - Odd                              */
/*                                        2 - Even                             */
/*                                        3 - Mark                             */
/*                                        4 - Space                            */
/* 6      | bDataBits  |   1   | Number Data bits (5, 6, 7, 8 or 16).          */
/*******************************************************************************/
static uint8_t lineCoding[7] // 115200bps, 1stop, no parity, 8bit
    = { 0x00, 0xC2, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08 };
```

and adjusted CDC_Control_FS function:

```
static int8_t CDC_Control_FS(uint8_t cmd, uint8_t* pbuf, uint16_t length)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 5 */
  switch(cmd)
  {
   ...
    case CDC_SET_LINE_CODING:
      memcpy(lineCoding, pbuf, sizeof(lineCoding));
    break;

    case CDC_GET_LINE_CODING:
      memcpy(pbuf, lineCoding, sizeof(lineCoding));
    break;
    ...
}
```

I hope this is still useful for you.

Comment: Your Welcome, i think ST has deleted these lines in the new repository. They better should add it again so people can program faster, thats mostly what people wanna do with usb CDC.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Michaël. I am running F7 Disco. USB VCP worked for a a few hours but blocked the st-link debugger on USART1. Now I have the opposite - ST-Link working on USART1 but USB VCP broken. I also commented out the FMC, DCMI, ETH and LTDC as per below. I think it may be FreeRTOS setting all IRQ priorities to 5.

Comment: Thanks. Really helpful answer. Saves a lot of time for me. It works also on Nucleo-F722ZE

Answer (score 0):

Firmware FW1.4.0 for STM32H7 works incorrect. I must used FW1.3.2 and CubeMX 5.2.1.

But if I init FMC bus, virtual COM port works incorrect again, if I comment initialization, it works correct again

```
MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();
//  MX_FMC_Init();
```

Interesting, what C functions: "fopen("COM6", "r+"), fwrite, fgetc, fclose" - work in Windows 10 with FW1.4.0 without port configuration. Error of FW1.4.0 is in writing port parameters (baud, bits or others) and virtual COM port Windows driver arises exception if cannot write parameters into USB device